infinite include loop in jq. Two modules that need each other and one of them by a third
I have 2 modules that will convert code into strings, module1.jq and module2.jq
module1 converts the code of obj1 that have this form
{ "code1":"254", "Object2s":[ {Object2}, {Object2} ] }
module2 converts the code of obj2 that have this form
{ "code1":"574", "Object1s":[ {Object1}, {Object1} ] }
As you can see, both object include each other, so in module1 it will be a statement
include "module2";
and in module2 there will be an statement
include "module1";
when using either of the modules, you´ll get an infinite loop.
module3.jq
include "module1";
How can stop this from happening?
Any help will be apreciated
I try to define kind of variables unique for each module and go like
In module1.jq
$module_module1 = 1;
if $module_module2 == 0 then include "module2";
In module2
$module_module2 = 1;
if $module_module1 == 0 then include "module1";
but it did not work.


The failure to detect circularity is a (well-known?) limitation (or bug); perhaps you would care to make an enhancement request for both the C and Go implementations?

The syntax of include directives does not provide for conditionality.


There are also some discrepancies between the C and Go implementations.
Notably:

if a-mod.jq defines a (e.g. def a: "a";), and
if b-mod.jq includes a-mod, and
if b.jq includes b-mod and invokes a

then gojq handles the situation as expected, but the C implementation gives a compilation error (running b.jq yields "a/0 is not defined").

In summary: for now at least,
apart from making enhancement requests and filing bug reports, it seems best not to expect too much from the module system.
